# Angular2 Meteor Uncaught no provider for ApplicationRef

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap, angular2-meteor

Starting up my application gives this error:

`Uncaught No provider for ApplicationRef!
ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull @ reflective_injector.js:786
ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault @ reflective_injector.js:814
ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey @ reflective_injector.js:777
ReflectiveInjector_.get @ reflective_injector.js:586
MeteorApp.bootstrap @ meteor_app.js:54
bootstrap @ bootstrap.js:9
meteorInstall.client.main.js @ main.ts:7
fileEvaluate @ install.js:153
require @ install.js:82
(anonymous function) @ volunteers.ts:95`

the `volunteers.ts:95` is the last file in my `/collections/` folder. When I delete `volunteers.ts` it jumps to the next last file in that folder.

I'm not sure what the errors above that line are referring to.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your package.json, I doubt that some newer packages installed cause the problem, try remove some `^` from your package.json, run `meteor npm install` again and see how the error turn into :-/